Как подключиться к серверу Postgre
Установил с сайта postgre, запускаю pgadmin, окно для ввода мастер-пароля не появляется.
Служба postgree (я на виндовс 10) работает.
Пробовал гуглить, но из того что нашёл - попробовал сделать, окно с паролем не появляется.
Пробую добавить свой сервер, но там как я понял должен быть уже существующий, т.е. нельзя инициировать создание нового сервера, так ведь?
В самом pgadmin не нашёл где можно подключиться к серверу.
Пробовал:

перезагружать пк
перезапускать службу
pgadmin запускал от имени администратора
интернет стабильный
брандмауер полностью выключен
антивирусов нет

Что можно сделать?
